# Rex match a string in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have few set of strings as mentioned below

```
/v4/users/1
/v4/users/1/vehicles/1
/v4/users
/v4/users?page=1
```

I would like to get `users` in all four cases as output using regex in Javascript

I tried below in https://www.regextester.com/

```
(?<=/v4/).*.(?=/[^/]*/)
```

It doesn't seem to come up right.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "in all three cases" ? what is with the fourth case?

Comment: sorry, four cases @caramba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with the positive lookbehind. This works:

```
'/v4/users/1/vehicles/1'.match(/(?<=\/v4\/)[^\/\?]*/)
```

This matches `users` because after the lookbehind you match everything until just before the next slash.

Comment: /v4/users?page=1 is not matching @Peter

Comment: (?<=\/v4\/)[^\/?]* this works @peter thanks

Comment: I meant "negated character class"

Answer (score 0):

`/\/v4\/(\w+)/g`

This will put `users` in a capture group. If you want you can make it a named group as well.

You can try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/0OOr0g/1